# Run image processing algorithn in python on S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am novice in aws services.

I have large images stroed in S3 bucekt and I want to iterate on each image and make some
basic image processing **without downloading them** (i.e., directly on the bucket), for example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
#some stuff that I don't know here....

for image in bucket:
   new_image = cv2.blur(image,(3,3))
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't do it** "directly in the bucket". S3 is object storage system, not a regular filesystem, and it does not allow for modifications of its objects in a same way as you can do on a regular filesystem.  You basically need to replace the object to modify it.

Depending on the size and nature of your image processing tasks (how long, how much ram, cpu they require) you can process them fairly easy. For example, you could use:

- [S3 Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html) to automatically run lambda function for all your images in the bucket.
- [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) useful to run image processing jobs in parallel, without lambda limitations. But requires a bit more setup than S3 Batch.
- Custom solutions based on EC2 instances or ECS containers. In most basic solution, you setup one instance which processes the image from the bucket one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you, tha's very helpful!, can I invoke my code for each one of your three sugestions "by demand"? meaning not upon event but upon my call?

Comment: @BennyK Yes, all of these options are "by demand". You have to set them up, and then manually invoke. For example, for S3 Batch, you need to provide a list of S3 objects (in your case images) to work on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without downloading an image.
So the process for you would be:

1. Download an image
2. Process it
3. Replace image on s3 bucket with the updated image

Comment: so what are the purpose of services like EC2 and Lambda?

Comment: How do you mean? EC2 is virtual machines, Lamda is for creating some code that will be run in response to some events in AWS.

Comment: And can't I invoke my code not in response to some event but, say, to (my) button press?

Comment: I believe you can trigger lambda function by clicking a button in AWS console. Or if your button sends HTTP request to AWS that triggers your lambda function to invoke